# Seems there's more to css precedence than w3.org is explaining

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have two simple css styles:

```
div
{
color: white;
}    

body
{
color: gray;
}
```

Each of these has a precedence value of 0,0,0,1.  Therefore, according to the rules, the second style should override the first, and all text enclosed in a div should be gray instead of white.  This is not what happens; the div style takes precedence no matter its position.  Presumably, there's something somewhere that says that a more specific element takes precedence over a less specific one or some such, but I can't find anything that says so.  Can anyone tell me where this behavior might be documented?

Comment: show html:
is it <div><body> or <body><div>?

Comment: @tehdoommarine: Did you really ask that seriously?

Comment: <div><body> would be invalid html

Comment: @BoltClock - was thinking potential cascade conflict since <div id = "div1"> <div id = "div2"> </div> </div> could lead to said issue

Comment: Yes, but how can a `body` exist after or inside a `div`...?

Comment: @BoltClock - Put it there with appendChild? http://jsfiddle.net/GL5qA/

Comment: @Alohci: Well - besides through manipulating the DOM...

Comment: <body> <div> </div> </body>.  Like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're correct that both rules have the same specificity - 0,0,0,1 - however they're not targeting the div element in the same way.

The body rule (gray text) matches the div, but only through inheritance - the div rule (white text) matches the div directly.

When an element inherits a value from its parent, it is inheriting its computed value, and as declared in the W3C spec every element goes through a four-step calculation.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#value-stages

> The final value of a property is the result of a four-step
>   calculation: the value is determined through specification (the
>   “specified value”), then resolved into a value that is used for
>   inheritance (the “computed value”), then converted into an absolute
>   value if necessary (the “used value”), and finally transformed
>   according to the limitations of the local environment (the “actual
>   value”).

So on the div the color white is the only 'specified' value, and so takes precedence. The color gray is only a computed value, via inheritance from the body tag.

At least, that's how I've interpreted the spec.

Comment: Good interpretation. This has everything to do with inheritance, and nothing to do with selector specificity - specificity only matters when the selectors apply to the same element, which isn't the case here. I should note though, that the computed value of `gray` is what is computed for `body`, but the value of `white` is computed for `div`, since `white` is specified for that particular element and so overrides the computed value for its parent which it would normally inherit from.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right. It's explained well in Eric Mayer's book on CSS